# Google calendar sync setup

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar, google-sync

I want  add my Google calendar to my outlook 2013 calendar. Calendar sync doesn't work with 2013 outlook. Have tried numerous things. Wasn't to be able to use this and sync with my android phone.

Answer (score 0):

First, login to your Google Calendar account. On the left column, select "calendars", and select the small green arrow that appears next to the calendar you would to sync. Click "calendar settings". Under "private address", click iCal. Copy the web link that appears. Don't click the link, or it will open in Outlook as a snapshot, which will not be synced. In outlook, on the tools menu, click "account settings". Paste the web link you copied, and click "add". From there, you can type the name you want the Google Calendar to appear in Outlook. For more information, check out [this link.](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/transfer-calendars-between-outlook-and-google-calendar-HA010167495.aspx#_Toc349292829)